# The fastest way to fetch data from the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter, fetch

There is a table of communications which contains IDs of content and the corresponding keys. It is necessary to organize fast search for a filtration in keys. If value of a key equally to null, approaches any content. For example, if the post inquiry comes 
**$ _POST == array (filter1 => 2, filter2 => 4, filter3 => 2, filter4 => null)**, then result will be the **array(content_ids => array(4, 7))**

id | content_id | filter1| filter2 | filter3 | filter4
1  | 1               | 1       |3         |1         |NULL
2  | 2               | 2       |6         |2         |2
3  | 3               | 1       |5         |1         |NULL
4  | 5               | 1       |1         |1         |5
***5  | 4               | 2       |4         |2         |7***

6  | 6               | 2       |2         |2         |NULL
***7  | 7               | 2       |4         |NULL  |NULL***

PS: The table will contain thousands of lines, and the number of filters will be equal 12

Comment: post the query what you have tried and you feel its slow.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the question is more about SQL rather than Codeigniter.

What you can do is to build the query that looks like

```sql
SELECT content_id
  FROM table1
 WHERE (? IS NULL OR filter1 = ? OR filter1 IS NULL)
   AND (? IS NULL OR filter2 = ? OR filter2 IS NULL)
   AND (? IS NULL OR filter3 = ? OR filter3 IS NULL)
   AND (? IS NULL OR filter4 = ? OR filter4 IS NULL)
```

where `?` are placeholder for actual filter values that you get via `POST`.

Output with your sample data:

```
| CONTENT_ID |
|------------|
|          4 |
|          7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6b46/5)** demo

Consider creating a covering index or indices (depending on actual data access patterns) for performance reasons.